# DataViewGrid is not displaying expected data

Tags: powershell, winforms, datatable, datagridview

My problem is that I don't know what the problem is. It is a problem with displaying the content of the variables `$VMName` and `$Output` pls let me know if you have any solution. The part which is not working is circled with exclamation marks and hashtags. Besides that I've copied the biggest part of my script in here in case someone wants to test it.

```
# Create the main window
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Serverkonfigurations-Export"
$form.Width = 555
$form.Height = 500

# static size
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedSingle
$form.MaximizeBox = $false

$DataGridView = New-Object Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(25, 50)
$DataGridView.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(490, 350)
$DataGridView.ReadOnly = $true
$DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($DataGridView)

# Create columns
$Column1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
$Column1.Name = "VM Name"
$Column1.HeaderText = "VM Name"
$Column1.Width = 272
$DataGridView.Columns.Add($Column1)

$Column2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
$Column2.Name = "CPU/RAM"
$Column2.HeaderText = "CPU/RAM"
$Column2.Width = 175
$DataGridView.Columns.Add($Column2)

# Get virtual machines
$VMs = Get-SCVirtualMachine | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*xenapp1*"}

#Start foreach-Schleife
foreach($VM in $VMs){

    $ProcessorCount = $VM.CPUCount
    $Memory = $VM.Memory
    $MemoryConfiguration = $VM.DynamicMemoryEnabled
    $MemorySize = $Memory / "1024"

    # Format for Output
    $OutputFormat = "{0}c/{1}G{2}"
    if($MemoryConfiguration -eq $true){

        $MemoryUnit = "d"
    }
    else{

        $MemoryUnit = "s"
    }

    # Result Output
    $VMName = $VM.Name 
    $Output = $OutputFormat -f $ProcessorCount, $MemorySize, $MemoryUnit

    $Output1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
        VMName = $VMName
        Config = $Output
    }  

}

######################################################################
! Create Data as datatable                                           !
! $dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable                      !
! $dataTable.Columns.Add("VM Name", [string]::typeid) | Out-Null     !
! $dataTable.Columns.Add("CPU/RAM", [string]::typeid) | Out-Null     !
! $dataRow = $dataTable.NewRow()                                     !
! $dataRow["VM Name"] = $VMName                                      !
! $dataRow["CPU/RAM"] = $Output                                      !
! $dataTable.Rows.Add($dataRow)                                      !
! $DataGridView.DataSource = $dataTable                              !
######################################################################

# Button creation
$button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button3.Text = "Export to CSV"
$button3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(330, 405)
$button3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,25)
$form.Controls.Add($button3)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(440, 405)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

# create copy button
$CopyButton = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$CopyButton.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point(195, 405)
$CopyButton.Size = New-Object Drawing.Size(125, 25)
$CopyButton.Text = "Copy marked cells"
$CopyButton.Add_Click({
    # Check if a cell is marked
    if ($DataGridView.SelectedCells.Count -gt 0) {
        # content of marked cells copy to clipboard
        $ClipboardData = ""
        foreach ($cell in $DataGridView.SelectedCells) {
            $ClipboardData += $cell.Value + "`t" # Tab als Trennzeichen verwenden
        }
        $ClipboardData | Set-Clipboard
    }
    else {
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Value cannot be null","Copy to Clipboard failed",0)
    }
})
$form.Controls.Add($CopyButton)

$text = "Dieses Script ist dazu da, die Serverkonfigurationen von den einzelnen Xenapp-Server auszulesen."
# Label for introduction
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = $text
$label.AutoSize = $true
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 20)
$form.Controls.Add($label)
```

These are the errors if I execute the script.

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "'dataType' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataType"
At C:\Scripts\000_In_Progress\nois\VMconfig_auslesen.ps1:72 char:1
+ $dataTable.Columns.Add("VM Name", [string]::typeid) | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
 
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "'dataType' argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: dataType"
At C:\Scripts\000_In_Progress\nois\VMconfig_auslesen.ps1:73 char:1
+ $dataTable.Columns.Add("CPU/RAM", [string]::typeid) | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException
 
Column 'VM Name' does not belong to table .
At C:\Scripts\000_In_Progress\nois\VMconfig_auslesen.ps1:75 char:1
+ $dataRow["VM Name"] = $VMName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
 
Column 'CPU/RAM' does not belong to table .
At C:\Scripts\000_In_Progress\nois\VMconfig_auslesen.ps1:76 char:1
+ $dataRow["CPU/RAM"] = $Output
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Comment: well what is `[string]::typeid` ? just remove that argument at it should be good

Comment: Thankyou @SantiagoSquarzon I don't get any errors anymore. Unfortunately there are still no changes to the Output. I don't get an Output

Comment: Either set `$DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = $true` and remove the Columns you have created, or keep your Columns and set their `DataPropertyName` to the name of the Column in the DataTable they're bound to -- BTW, to add a Row, you just need `$dataTable.Rows.Add($VMName, $Output)`

Comment: BTW2, you may want to move the `.Rows.Add()` method inside the loop, unless you just want to show the last available result -- Not clear what `$Output1` is or what it's for

Comment: oh yeah, that actually works pretty fine. Thanks for the advice. Really appreciate it

Comment: Try : $DataGridView.Columns.Add($Column1, [System.Type]::GetType('string'))